# wp_query get post custom taxonomy in search.php

Tags: customization, query, taxonomy

domain.com/?cat=id custom taxonomy not get post but category get to post

How do you write wp_query get post taxonomy?

```
<?php
$args_my_query = array(
    'post_type'    =>    'post',
    'taxonomy' =>  'khu-vuc',
    'field' => 'id',
    'terms' => array($post->ID),
);
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args_my_query );
?>
```

code in file search.php

Comment: Are you trying to filter search so it only searches inside a category? Your english is a little difficult to understand

Comment: i cant domain.com/?cat=id get post custom taxonomy

Comment: I don't understand, please say what you are trying to do, what you did, what you expected, and then what actually happened